# Apache Ant installation Windows 7

Tags: java, xml, apache, ant, build

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I do ant -version on command line, it says not recognized. Any ideas on how to fix? I'm trying to make a build.xml for a Java project.

Comment: Start  a command window. Then check value of %path%

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:
\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\S
ystem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\
ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\P
hysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin

Comment: Your `JAVA_HOME` and `ANT_HOME` aren't being expanded. Which means they aren't set yet. Exit the command window, and start a new one. Check if they're set after you do that. Otherwise, logout and log back in. Or maybe User Environment Variables don't affect System Environment Variabels. But I think it's the first one.

Comment: So I tried log off, log on, same result. I moved them over to System Environment Variables, still nothing.

I'm doing echo %PATH% in command line by the way.

Comment: Did you try %ANT_HOME%/bin/ant?

Comment: Oh, your ant installation looks different. It must have a bin folder? Did you build this from source? There will be a zip in the "dist" folder. That must be extracted and used as ant home.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `JAVA_HOME` and `ANT_HOME` as User environment variable. The path you set is in System environment variable.

You can fix it by many ways. One way will be to define `JAVA_HOME` and `ANT_HOME` in System Environment setting.

Another way will be to modify `PATH` variable in user environment section.

Comment: I've moved them over to System Variables now, still nothing.

Comment: The paths show up correctly now but ant -version does nothing. Could this be because there is no \bin file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME and PATH are set correctly.

ANT_HOME is used by the launcher script for finding the libraries.

JAVA_HOME is used by the launcher for finding the JDK/JRE to use. (JDK is recommended as some tasks require the java tools.) If not set, the launcher tries to find one via the %PATH% environment variable.

PATH is set for user convenience. With that set you can just start ant instead of always typing the/complete/path/to/your/ant/installation/bin/ant.

[image]

[image]

Set these variables correctly and open a new cmd window (don't use old cmd window, please open new window)

type echo %PATH% , should show java and ant 
[image]

Open command window(cmd) and type
  `java -version`

[image]
If this shows java version , this means java is in your path and working.

finally type ant -version

[image]